# Hack IKEA Trofast drawers

Tags: diy-3d-printer, 3d-design

I'm looking to hack an IKEA Trofast storage unit.

It's 3 drawers high (10 cm for each drawer), I would like to make it 6 drawers high, with thinner drawers (4 cm for each drawer). Which means :

- design the new drawer since no 3D map exists on Thingiverse for that drawer
- print them
- put additional rails which I found [here](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3582819)

So my questions are :

- Is it easy to design a thin drawer from a higher one ?
- since the high drawer is 43 x 30 x 10 cm, is it easy to scan/print a big object like that one ?

The Trofast unit I'm trying to hack :

[image: IKEA Trofast storage unit]

**EDIT** : Juste to make it clearer, I don't want to make a larger storage unit. I want to print thiner drawers, to be able to put 6 of them in this particular storage unit (so with the same height).

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Why scan, it would be easier to design from scratch. Also, you need a very big printer, otherwise you're forced to print it in parts. I guess it is much cheaper to buy second hand storage units, reuse the rails and shorten the drawers by cutting out a strip and rivet them back together. I don't see FDM as the preferred manufacturing process, hence a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Parts of the remodeling might be 3D printed, but the sheer print size makes it uneconomical to print whole units. Also, your questions are open: *Easy* is a rating that comes with skill with your chosen program. To me, it's easy to make a drawer in Fusion360 but very hard in AutoCAD.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added an Edit. I asked if it was easy in the way "feasible" because I will probably go to a fablab to actually print/design the drawer.

Comment: You are going to have trouble finding a printer that will print 40cm in one piece. Most consumer level printers top out around 20 cm and a few go to 30 cm. To be able to print 40 cm, you will probably have to find somewhere with expensive industrial grade printers. Otherwise, you can print it in pieces and glue them together, but then you may have a problem with lack of strength.

Comment: I'd recommend hitting a container store and seeing what already exists.  After that build modifications (some of which can be 3D printed) to the closest one that would let you use them on those rails.